# How to deploy a docker image from dockerhub to a server with github actions

Tags: docker, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I want to implement CI/CD for my application, so far I have managed to build and upload my image on docker hub with GitHub actions. Now I need a way to pull that image on my VPS and run the docker image. I do not know how to achieve that, I tried multiple youtube videos but none show that.
Could someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually flow after image exists in Dockerhub is:

- you use the docker [login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) command to log in to the user which has permissions to pull the image
- You can either pre pull the image using the docker [pull](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) command or you can straight on just use the docker [run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) command and it will pull the image if not existing and run it.

For an example with Nginx, the image resides in [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) and with help of [official docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/) you can see

```
docker run --name mynginx1 -p 80:80 -d nginx
```

the command which will pull the Nginx image (latest in this case) and run the container with the name of mynigninx1 and expose the port on host 80 and map it to port 80 inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is:

1. Setup a [webhook](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) on vps, this serves as a webhook server, define a endpoint and a script to redeploy (Will be executed when endpoint is called and met)
2. In your GitHub ctions flow, add new a step, send a request to this webhook server endpoint

Answer (score -1):

There is a docker image you can run on your server to watch your working or selected docker containers and when there is a new push to the docker hub registry then it will update your docker image of your project
Its called watchtower
containrrr/watchtower